# Recursicely call data in a mongodb with node

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am creating a login system and i want to implement a username system automatically after registration with the user first-name and last-name. Everything is working fine but in the case if the registered user with the same first-name and last-name is already in the system i want to concatenate a incrmental number to it.
Example if : firstname:Badmus Lastname:Kabiru is in the system as badmus.kabiru and the newly registered user is also named so the new user username will be badmus.kabiru.1 the next will be badmus.kabiru.2.
My code sample are.

```
  assignUserTrendname: function(req_username, callback){
let userNewname = fetchUserName(req_username);
let inc = 1, newlyAssignUsername;
userNewname.then((usernames) =>  {
    console.log(req_username+" ...................... "+usernames); //The data from the database is loging out
    if (usernames.atusername == null || usernames.atusername == undefined) {
        newlyAssignUsername = req_username;  
        console.log("Assign automaticaly "+ newlyAssignUsername);
    } else {
        newlyAssignUsername = req_username;
        console.log(`Username Result is DB: ${usernames.atusername} Req: ${newlyAssignUsername} Search ${inc}`);
        if(usernames.atusername.toString() == newlyAssignUsername.toString()){
            console.log("User name exit and inc is "+ inc);
            inc++;
            newlyAssignUsername = `${req_username}.${inc}`;
            console.log("New search..."+ newlyAssignUsername);
            fetchusernames(newlyAssignUsername); // These is not fetching from the database
        }
        newlyAssignUsername = `${req_username}.${inc}`;
    }
    console.log("Assigned is ......"+ newTrendname);
     callback(null, newTrendname);
})
.catch((err)=> {console.log(err); throw err;});
  }

function fetchUserName(trendname){
   return Trender.getUserByTrendname(trendname);
}
```

If i am taking the wrong route please let me know. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario that `your.username` already exists you can search your Users with a regex pattern: `((?:your\.username)\d+$)`. This will get all records that match: `your.username{num}` where `{num}` is any number. If your username's are formatted as `your.username.123` the pattern would be: `((?:your\.username\.)\d+$)`.

Assuming this returns an array, `existing_users`, you can count the records, since you'll always be incrementing by one, which will give you your next incremented number. Pseudo code:

`let inc = existing_users.length + 1;`

However, in the scenario that you delete a user your count is going to be off. You would need to loop over your `existing_users` and extract the number at the end and only keep the largest number.

```
let largest_num = 0;
existing_users.forEach(user => {
  let num = user.match(/\d+$/);
  if ( num != null && parseInt(num[0]) > largest_num ) {
    largest_num = num[0];
  }
});
```

Then you could do the same as above: `let inc = largest_num + 1` and add that to your `your.username` string.

I do not know what library/framework you're using to search your MongoDB so I cannot write a query and function snippet.

Comment: I am using mongoose as my ORM so you can write any code on it. I will understand. Thanks I really  appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot write your code for you. A general regex has already been given that could be a potential way to solve your problem. If you go that route you can make use of the $regex operator. If you were to store the increment of the username as a separate field you could also sort by that to get the max value as well.

Here is an example of that:

```
db.users.find({
  username: {
    $regex: < Your Regex Here >
  }
}).sort({
  usernameIncrement: -1
}).limit(1);
```

Please see:

- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Comment: Thanks so much. I never want anybody to write my core your sample is more than enough.